# Having a hard time getting the right probability outcome (js beginner)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple rolling the dice mechanic with probabilities, if pass the level increase, if fail it decrease and if destroyed usually it resets to a certain level, but I'm having a hard time getting the right results, I am not sure if the outcome is supposed to be like this and just my intuition is wrong or something is actually messing it up.

Basically I am making a while loop that while below certain level it will roll the dice and given the results it will do something accordingly to the rates I input (40% for pass, 59.4% for fail and 0.6% to destroy). But when I do a test with 1000 tries, it always return me an average of destroyed way higher than 0.6%. I don't know if my test function is wrong, if the way I'm testing is wrong, if something on my loop is messing up the probabilities outcome.

```
function checkPass(successRate, failRate, destroyRate) {
    let number = Math.random();
    if (number < successRate) {
        return 1;
    } else if (number < failRate) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

function starforceSim(itemLevel) {
    let newObj = {"level": 10, "totalMeso": 0, "destroyed": 0};
    while (newObj.level < 11) {
        if (newObj.level == 10) {
            let passOutcome = checkPass(0.4, 0.994, 1)
            if (passOutcome == 1) {
                //newObj.totalMeso = newObj.totalMeso + (Math.round(1000 + (Math.pow(itemLevel, 3)) * (Math.pow(newObj.starlevel + 1, 2.7)) / 400));
                newObj.level = newObj.level + 1;
            } else if (passOutcome == 0) {
                //newObj.totalMeso = newObj.totalMeso + (Math.round(1000 + (Math.pow(itemLevel, 3)) * (Math.pow(newObj.starlevel + 1, 2.7)) / 400));
                //newObj.level = newObj.level - 1;
            } else {
                //newObj.totalMeso = newObj.totalMeso + (Math.round(1000 + (Math.pow(itemLevel, 3)) * (Math.pow(newObj.starlevel + 1, 2.7)) / 400));
                newObj.destroyed = newObj.destroyed + 1
            }
        } 
    }
    return newObj;
}


let counter = 0;

for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    let n = starforceSim(140);
    if (n.destroyed > 0) {
        counter++
    }
}
console.log(counter);
```

I disabled the decrease level when it fails just to focus on the destroy rates.

Is there a better way to code probabilities or to test them? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: When I find myself in a similar situation what I typically do is add some console output that makes it easy for me to see EXACTLY which probability setting is currently in effect.  Then I do not have to trust my intuition about the result of the probability calculation(s).    Another approach would be to test your individual probability values in isolation from each other -- IOW leave out the conditional code that dynamically changes the probability setting and run a bunch of tests with a single probability value -- that should help you determine if the calculations are correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Math.random is only pseudo-random<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)</sup>

This means you may not get a perfectly uniform distribution. In my own fiddling, it seems like randomness might get worse if you generate many values in rapid succession <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

If you want a better source of randomness, check out [Crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues).

I don't see anything wrong with your code. I think your expectations are just off. To verify that this is caused by lame randomness, take David Tansey's advice and study just the randomness output.

You may also notice different randomness quality in different browsers (or, different Javascript engines).